# How do I get the correct output for the try/catch statement?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to add a new item in the list by inputting the number for the position of the list. When I run this code for the app, even without inputting a number, only the catch statement is executed. How do I get the try statement executed? Here is the code that I typed (Please ignore the lines of the code for manually adding items to the list l1 unless it have to change to fix my problem):

```
public void m(View view) {
    //Define reference for the list
    List<Integer> l1;

    int x;
    int y;
    int z; //For storing removed item 
    EditText input;
    TextView tv;
    int pos; //For position of the list that user input

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_input);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_answer);

    pos = input.getInputType();

    //Create the list 
    l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Add items to the list l1
    l1.add(0, 20);
    l1.add(1, 52);

    //Display the size 
    tv.setText("List's size is " + l1.size() + "\n");

    //Retrieve an item
    x = l1.get(0);

    //Display the retrieved item
    tv.append("Retrieved value is " + x + "\n"); 

    //Add more items to the list, but change its position
    l1.add(0, 61);
    l1.add(1, 17);
    l1.add(2, 6);

    //Show the updated size
    tv.append("After adding more items, List's size is " + l1.size() + "\n");

    //Retrieve an item at position (or index) 2
    y = l1.get(2);

    //Display the new retrieved item
    tv.append("The second retrieved item is " + y + "\n");

    //Remove an item at position 3
    z = l1.get(3);
    tv.append("Next, I will remove the item at position 3, which is " + z + "\n");
    l1.remove(3);

    //Display the final size
    tv.append("After removing one item from the list, List's size is " + l1.size() + "\n");

    //Use the toast message
    try {
        l1.add(pos, 777);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added item to the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not add item to thie list. Bad index:" + 
                        pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want something that could be sure, try a hashmap instead of a list

Comment: The `try` block will be executed completely if no error happens in it, if some error happens, the `catch` block is getting executed. This is called [Exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling), and it is a nice mechanism to stop your application from crashing... So, in your code, you are probably using an invalid `pos` value and you are getting exception because of that (check the log)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read *pos* as ;

```
pos = input.getInputType();
```

This might cause *IndexOutOfBoundsException* at all times. Instead you might want to convert EditText content into int somewhere around this line of code ;

```
pos = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

Plus add some sanity checking to avoid integer parse exceptions.